# Unable to Properly obtain List Data from class

Tags: python, list

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,cargo = None, next = None):
    self.cargo = cargo
    self.next = next
    
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.cargo)

def printList(node):
    Nide = [node]
    while node:
        node = node.next
        Nide.append(node)
    print(str(Nide))

node1 = Node(1)
node2 = Node(2)
node3 = Node(3) 
node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node1.printList()
```

I am unable to properly collect list data(it should be in format of [1,2,3])

```
[<__main__.Node object at 0x0000012C08495FD0>, <__main__.Node object at 0x0000012C08495F10>, <__main__.Node object at 0x0000012C08495E20>, None]
```

I keep getting it like this.

Comment: In a list's `__repr__` you get the `__repr__`, not the `__str__`.

Comment: Is the indentation of the code the same on your end, or was it changed when it was added to the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.__str__` displays the elements `repr` representation. So you should either add a `__repr__` method to your Node class or (better) just add the node's cargo to the helper `list`:

```
def printList(node):
    Nide = []
    while node:
        Nide.append(node.cargo)  # add cargo only!
        node = node.next
    print(str(Nide))
```

This also fixes the `None` at the end of your list.